# How to transfer files from host to DOS QEMU C drive?

Tags: linux, debian, qemu, ms-dos

I downloaded MS-DOS 6.22 and I installed it on my qemu. Now I want to transfer files from host to my DOS QEMU C drive.

**Edit**: My host operating system is 64-bit Linux (Debian).

Comment: What is your host operating system. DOS 6 is 16-bit and will not communicate with any 64-bit machine. You would have to attach a CD to the DOS machine and transfer files that way.

Comment: @John I edited my question.

Comment: Modern Linux is also 64-bit. Did you install Debian 32-bit?

Comment: @John I edited my question again.

Comment: Thanks. You will need to attach a CD to the DOS system and transfer files that way. You cannot network DOS to a 64-bit machine.

Comment: If you have an external Floppy drive that Debian can understand, DOS will see that very well and you can use that. I use a 3.5 inch USB floppy but you need a proper drive for DOS as DOS cannot see USB.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU can automatically create a virtual FAT disk image from a directory tree.
To use it, create dir on host system, for example "share".

```
mkdir share
```

Copy required files to 'share' directory.
Start QEMU with additional virtual drive 'd:' created from '/share':

```
qemu-system-x86_64 msdos.img -hdb fat:./share/
```

If you need to write to disk 'd:' add `rw`:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 msdos.img -hdb fat:rw:./share/
```

To access files, type in MS-DOS command line:

```
d:
dir
```

Note. You should never write to the FAT directory on the host system while accessing it with the guest system. If want to add new files to 'share', shutdown the virtual machine before.

For move info see "Virtual FAT disk images" in [QEMU documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/images.html#virtual-fat-disk-images)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).